# How do I construct design matrix in NumPy (for linear regression)?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

For this lab I need to sample 150 x-values from a Normal distribution using a mean of 0 and standard deviation of 10, then from the x-values construct a design matrix using the features {1,x,x^2}.

We have to sample parameters and then use the design matrix to create y values for regression data.

The problem is that my design matrix isn't square, and the Moore-Penrose Pseduoinverse needs square matrices, but I don't know how to get that to work given the earlier setup of the lab?

This is what I've done

```
#Linear Regression Lab
import numpy as np
import math
data = np.random.normal(0, 10, 150)

design_matrix = np.zeros((150,3))

for i in range(150):
    design_matrix[i][0] = 1
    design_matrix[i][1] = data[i]
    design_matrix[i][2] = pow(data[i], 2)


print("-------------------Design Matrix---------------------")
print("|--------1--------|-------x-------|--------x^2--------|")
print(design_matrix[:20])

#sampling paramters

theta_0 = np.random.uniform(low = -30, high = 20)
theta_1 = np.random.uniform(low = -30, high = 20)
theta_2 = np.random.uniform(low = -30, high = 20)

print(theta_0, theta_1, theta_2)

theta = np.array([theta_0, theta_1, theta_2])

theta = np.transpose(theta)

#moore penrose psuedo inverse
MPpi = np.linalg.pinv(design_matrix) ##problem here

y_values = np.linalg.inv(MPpi)
```

Comment: is the requirement to use ***only*** numpy? IIRC statsmodels package (uses patsy) can get you the design matrix pretty easily for linear regressions. If you must do it only using numpy, for linear regression you take the `pinv` of the square matrix `X^TX` where `X` is the (n x p) design matrix and `^T` is transpose. so the matrix `X^TX` is (p x p)

Answer (score 0):

**Feel free to edit this incomplete answer**

After running this code on [Repl](https://repl.it/languages/python3), I got the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 32, in <module>
    y_values = np.linalg.inv(MPpi)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in inv
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 542, in inv
    _assert_stacked_square(a)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 213, in _assert_stacked_square
    raise LinAlgError('Last 2 dimensions of the array mustbe square')
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
```

The first error propagates from taking the inverse of `MPpi`

By looking at the docs, it seems that `pinv` switches the last two dimensions [e.g., an `m` x `n` matrix becomes `n` x `m`], so we will need to format the matrix before calculating the psuedoinverse

As far as the Moore Penrose inverse AKA `pinv` is concerned, [this article](http://buzzard.ups.edu/courses/2014spring/420projects/math420-UPS-spring-2014-macausland-pseudo-inverse.pdf) suggests that multiplying `MPpi*data`, which will yield x_0 {notation from Ross MacAusland}, which is the best fit for your least squares regression.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, let me try that.

Comment: @NkululekoKubeka Let me know how it goes!! would love to learn more about sigmoid functions :)

Comment: Also, could you link to an article about constructing a design matrix? would help me help you